# highcharts: how can I show the floats as datetime in the xAxis correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot the following example data. I want to show the x-Axis as the DateTime from the float numbers. But it keeps on shown as 1970-01-01. Can someone help me to understand how can I get it correctly?

I copied the high charts example as below. But I want to show the x-axis as date, like '2017-03-20', rather than the original floats.

Thank you very much for your help!

Thank you.

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
        credits: {
            text: 'Songhuiming',
            href: 'http://www.songhuiming.com'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {day: '%Y-%b-%d'},
            categories: [1489298400000.0, 1492923600000.0, 1492318800000.0, 1480226400000.0, 1494133200000.0, 1490504400000.0, 1488088800000.0, 1475384400000.0, 1493528400000.0, 1491109200000.0, 1480831200000.0, 1471755600000.0],
            crosshair: true,
            labels: {rotation: 90, step: 2}
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [110, 105, 104, 96, 102, 93, 93, 105, 118, 119, 101, 94],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the proprity dateTimeLabelFormats is not working fine so you can just convert you float timestamp to a formatted date string  :

```
new Date(1489298400000.0).toLocaleDateString()
```

Here the complete example :

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
        credits: {
            text: 'Songhuiming',
            href: 'http://www.songhuiming.com'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: [new Date(1489298400000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1492923600000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1492318800000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1480226400000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1494133200000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1490504400000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1488088800000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1475384400000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1493528400000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1491109200000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1480831200000.0).toLocaleDateString(), new Date(1471755600000.0).toLocaleDateString()],
            crosshair: true,
            labels: {rotation: 90, step: 2}
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [110, 105, 104, 96, 102, 93, 93, 105, 118, 119, 101, 94],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning manually formatted timestamps to `categories` is not a good approach here. Highcharts already has built in mechanism for handling axis' datetime labels.

First change the `type` of your x axis to `datetime`. Then use timestamps as x values for points. It can be done either by explicitly assigning specific timestamp to every point or by using `pointInterval` combined with `pointStart` (when the distance between points is constant).

**Doc about data formats**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

**Doc about types of axes**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

**API references**:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval